# I have two data frames which are similar in structure, I need to update one of the data frame based on the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below are the tables in pandas DF, I am trying to merge two frames DF1 and DF2 based on columns **cat**, **sub_cat** and **date** so these columns act as merge criteria and update only the column **count**. Also, there could be additional data in DF2 which needs to be blindly added to the resulting DF if there is no match in the DF1 (based on the mentioned columns).

DF1

|  | cat | sub_cat | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **cat_1** | **sub_cat_1** | **2020-02-01** | 1 |
| 2 | cat_2 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-02-01 | 2 |
| 3 | cat_2 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-01-20 | 8 |
| 4 | cat_1 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-02-02 | 0 |

DF2

|  | cat | sub_cat | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **cat_1** | **sub_cat_1** | **2020-02-01** | 3 |
| 2 | cat_2 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-02-01 | 2 |
| 3 | cat_3 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-02-02 | 5 |

Here is the resulting DF3

|  | cat | sub_cat | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **cat_1** | **sub_cat_1** | **2020-02-01** | 3 |
| 2 | cat_2 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-02-01 | 2 |
| **3** | **cat_3** | **sub_cat_1** | **2020-02-02** | 5 |
| 4 | cat_2 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-01-20 | 8 |
| 5 | cat_1 | sub_cat_1 | 2020-02-02 | 0 |

I have highlighted the rows that are merged/added for reference.

I did refer to other questions/answer and tried a bit using **df.set_index** by as below

```
df1.set_index(['cat', 'sub_cat', 'date'])
df2.set_index(['cat', 'sub_cat', 'date'])
df1.update(df2)
```

but the above code is also replacing the dates which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

### edited - reproducing your case

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r''' cat sub_cat date    count
1   cat_1   sub_cat_1   2020-02-01  1
2   cat_2   sub_cat_1   2020-02-01  2
3   cat_2   sub_cat_1   2020-01-20  8
4   cat_1   sub_cat_1   2020-02-02  0'''), sep='\t', index_col=0)

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r''' cat sub_cat date    count
1   cat_1   sub_cat_1   2020-02-01  3
2   cat_2   sub_cat_1   2020-02-01  2
3   cat_3   sub_cat_1   2020-02-02  5'''), sep='\t', index_col=0)

cols = ['cat', 'sub_cat', 'date']
df1 = df1.set_index(cols)
df2 = df2.set_index(cols)

df1.update(df2)
```

**Output**

```
                            count
cat   sub_cat   date
cat_1 sub_cat_1 2020-02-01    3.0
cat_2 sub_cat_1 2020-02-01    2.0
                2020-01-20    8.0
cat_1 sub_cat_1 2020-02-02    0.0
```

Maybe you could do `pd.concat` then `drop_duplicates` with subset={your_index_cols} and keep='last'

Comment: I do not need to aggregate the count, all I need is the updated data frame.

Comment: you won't be able to update a record if there is no key in df1. for example, cat_3 will never appear. @user3801185